# Views Calendar Pager Skips a Month Forward

Tags: 7, views, paging, datetime

In our calendar constructed by Views, the pager (also constructed by Views) skips a month when you hit next. *However,* the "previous" pager button only goes back one month. So it goes forward two months and back one...

Has anyone else experienced this? I've tried messing with the pager settings, but to no avail. This calendar was added to the site before my time, so I don't really know what to look for, but if you need more info, let me know and I'll try to find it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the Date module, fixed by this simple RTBC patch in comment #35

https://www.drupal.org/node/2375235#comment-10205617